# unable to load private key on the virtual smart card

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11, opensc, pkcs#15

problem description

I have used bixVirtualReader with OpenSC-isoApplet
but I am unable to load private key on the smart card

what I tried

1. I tried this instruction after creating my 2048/rsa key generating

   ```
    pkcs15-init --store-private-key key.pem --auth-id 01 --pin 1234
   ```

   but it returns following error

   Failed to store private key: Not allowed

   I run this command which says does not have any certificate

   ```
    pkcs15-tool -c
   ```

   Using reader with a card: Bix VIRTUAL_CARD_READER 0

   and also this command which says does not have any key

   ```
    pkcs15-tool -k
   ```

   Using reader with a card: Bix VIRTUAL_CARD_READER 0
2. I also tried with these commands

   ```
    pkcs15-init --create-pkcs15

    pkcs15-init --store-certificate publickey.pem --label myKey --auth-id FF --id 01 --format pem --pin 1234

    pkcs15-init --generate-key "rsa/2048" --auth-id "FF" --label "myKey" --id "1"
   ```

   it works but when I run certutil -scinfo it gives the
   No cert retrieved for reader: Bix VIRTUAL_CARD_READER 0

   please guide me to find the solution how to add valid certificate to my virtual smart card
   any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I enabled key import in the isoApplet DEF_PRIVATE_KEY_IMPORT_ALLOWED = true , and the problem solved